# Unexpected end of JSON input when using Promise.all() and put method in fetch

Tags: javascript, json, promise, fetch

I encountered a problem using Javascript, when I try to get mail content from an API and update its read status concurrently. The error message in the console is:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at inbox.js:98
```

The error promise in the log is as below.

```
1: Promise
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "rejected"
[[PromiseResult]]: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/mail/inbox.js:98:30
message: "Unexpected end of JSON input"
stack: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input\n    at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/mail/inbox.js:98:30"
```

The code in line #98 is:

```
let res2 = response[1].json();
```

The full js code is as below. I have checked promises called `res1` and `res2`. It seems that the problem lies in `res2` since its return is `rejected`. I tried different ways to resolve it, but failed. I also don't understand why it is not caught by the `catch` function. Thank you in advance.

Though it returns `SyntaxError` every time. Both `fetch` functions have worked already...

```
async function show_single_mail(email_id){
 
  // Show content of selected email

  document.querySelector('#mails_table').style.display = 'none';

  const email_div = document.createElement('div');
  document.querySelector('#emails-view').append(email_div);

  // Obtain email content and update its read status concurrently

  const option2 = {
    method: 'PUT', 
    body: JSON.stringify({read: true})}

  Promise.all([fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`), fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`, option2)])
    .then(response => {
      let res1 = response[0].json();
      let res2 = response[1].json();
      console.log([res1, res2]);
      return Promise.all([res1, res2])
    })
    .then(results => {
      result = results[0];
      email_div.innerHTML = 
      `<h3>Subject: ${result.subject}</h3><br>` +
      `<p>Sender: ${result.sender}</p><br>`+
      `<p>Receiver: ${result.recipients}</p><br>`+
      `<p>Time: ${result.timestamp}</p><br>`+
      `<p>Content: ${result.body}</p>`;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: What is the content of `response[1]`? It seems like it's not (valid) JSON

Comment: `.json()` is also a promise...  The easiest way to do it is to convert your first `.then` block callback to `async` and then use `await` on the `.json()` calls

Comment: `fetch` doesn't reject on a non-success status code (ie a statuscode 4xx), so you have to check the result yourself. check  if `response[0].status == 2xx` and `response[1].status == 2xx` first before you access the response's body. Seems the server is not sending a JSON object, when the status is 4xx. So when you call `res.json()` on an failed request, it throws an error becasue the body is not a valid jsn

Comment: You can also change the `.json()` to `.text()` and log the value of `results` in the next `.then()` so you can see what is actually returned form the server. (Or use your browser's developer tools Network tab to see the response.)

Comment: I tried to add ```async``` and ```await``` on the ```.json()```. It does not work as well. The issue is still there. I already have the ```Promise.all()``` there. Has it already fulfilled the asynchronous requirement?

Comment: @johnwow Because this issue isn't the asynchronicity, but the value that is returned from the server. We can't see that so we can't really help you with it. Try to do what I suggested in my last comment, so you can actually see what is returned from your server. (Because according to your error message, it ins't valid JSON.)

Comment: Got it, I will have a try.@Ivar

Comment: I have tried it and I have updated the result here@Ivar But I still did not find any evidence where it is wrong.

Comment: Have you changed `response[1].json()` to `response[1].text()`? Because that shouldn't show the message you added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing two parallel requests with

```
Promise.all([fetch(...), fetch(...)])
```

which is fine. But when you handle your results, you are not checking, whether the requests were sucessfull or not, and `fetch` doesn't reject on 4xx status codes. Furthermore, your server obviously does not return JSON for an unsuccessful request but only text. It may even be, that the second request succeeds, but doesn't have a valid json body. Nobody knows what your API really does.

When you now do

```
.then(responses => {
   responses[0].json();  //this response has a valid json body
   responses[1].json();  //this one doesn't
})
```

the body of `response[1]` can't be parsed as json (which `responses[1].json()` tries to do). And thus, an error is thrown. So you have to check first, if your requests were successful/returned json before you can read their body

```
.then(responses => {
   let s = responses.filter(x => x.ok);  //status == 2xx
   let f = responses.filter(x => !x.ok); //status != 2xx  
   //do something with failed requests and
   //only read the body for successful responses
   //return Promise.all(s.map(x => x.json()); 

   //or try to read json for successful and text for unsuccessful responsees
   //return Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.ok ? r.json() : r.text()));

   //or try to check the contenttype of the responses (if the server correctly sets them
   //return Promise.all(responses.map(r => r.headers.get("content-type").includes("application/json") 
   //    ? res.json()
   //    : res.text()
   //  ));
})
.then(responses => {
  //display them
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is helpful. I examined my code and solved the problem with the code below. I think that the problem may be caused by the different returns from ```fetch.POST``` and ```fetch.PUT```. The return of ```fetch.PUT``` seems cannot be merged with ```fetch.POST```. ```Promise.all([fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`), fetch(`/emails/${email_id}`, option2)]).then(responses => {return responses[0].json()}).then(result => {console.log(result);```